# Is there anything for you if you return to spawn island?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Watching the PUBG invitational, I realise that the island where the lobby is (the minute before you get in the plane) is still on the map.

While in the match, can you return to that lobby island, and is there any loot there?

Can you go and get the test weapons for instance? I heard that some pretty rare weapons like the tommy gun can be found on the island while waiting, would they still be there?

Comment: Be careful though, I followed someone there, beached my boat and stole theirs, they had a long swim back...

Comment: Go watch the solo matches. EVERMORE (I think?) went out there and you can see the camera follow him around a bit picking up loot.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Yes you can return to spawn Island, No the weapons on the tables will not be there.**

If you have a lucky plane ride and are able to drop on the northeast coast of the Main Island, and you are able to find a boat, there is usually enough time to ride over to Spawn Island and return before the circle shrinks.

In terms of what sort of loot you can expect to find, all of the "testing weapons" that are placed during the setting up game-phase are removed before loot is spawned so no chance of finding crate-only weapons just lying around. The island does have a decent amount of loot (usually enough for Duo's but a full squad will probably find it lacking) with a decent chance of finding military-grade gear. ([See Map Below](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=898402255))

<sup>Click/tap on the image below to view the higher-resolution, original image.</sup>
[image: PUBG MAP]

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can return to this island, just take a boat !

There will be some weapons in the underground bunker or in the buildings but none on the outdoors tables.
The rare weapons like the AWM can be found in supply drops, not on the starting island.

Comment: As of recently, the Tommy gun no longer appears in drops but normally.